# Confusion with usage of strcmp() for number strings

Tags: c, arrays, string, 2d, strcmp

```
{
    char array[2][10]={"3234","5"};
    int n=strcmp(array+0,array+1);
    printf("%d",n);

}
```

- The following code prints -1, event though 3234>5.
- It however prints 1 if the first number is 5234 or 6234 etc.
- What is the logic behind the results?(Are only the first digits taken
  into account?)
- **So, is there a way to compare two number strings without comapring
  their actual integer values?**

Comment: This is implentation defined behaviour, glibc uses the following approach: `return c1 - c2;` where `c1` and `c2` are `unsigned char`s

Comment: "Compares two null-terminated byte strings **lexicographically**" (from [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp))

Comment: Hint: a number with more digits is always greater than a number with fewer digits.

Comment: In any case, why does comparing 3234 which has more digits than 5 show -1

Comment: @DavidRanieri: The sign of the result is defined by the C standard (it is not implementation-defined), and that is what the question is about.

Comment: What would you expect if the two strings were "cbcd" and "e"? Same thing applies here.

Comment: @EricPostpischil What is the logic behind the results? is the question, and I'm talking about the results : _The strcmp function returns an integer greater than, equal to, or less than zero, accordingly as the string pointed to by s1 is greater than, equal to, or less than the string_.  So the result is implementation defined even if the sign is defined by the C standard.

Comment: @DavidRanieri: Tne question is about the sign of the result. OP is puzzled why `"3234"` is reported to be less than `"5"` but `"5234"` is not. That ordering is not implementation-defined. Why the result is −1 rather than, say, −5 is not part of the question.

Comment: @EricPostpischil really? I don't see the word "sign" in the question

Comment: @DavidRanieri: Yes, really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the logic behind the results?

`strcmp` compares characters in the strings, using their values as `unsigned char`. First, it compares the first character of one string with the first character of the other. If they differ, it reports the first string is “lesser than” the second if its character is lesser than the other’s and it reports “greater than” if the first string’s character is greater. If the characters are equal, then `strcmp` compares the second characters of the strings, then the third, and so on. (If one string is shorter than the other but is identical up to its end, the null character that terminates it will cause it to be lesser than the other string.)

> So, is there a way to compare two number strings without comapring their actual integer values?

There is no standard library routine for this. You could write a routine for it.